# Issue Paging with UITableView

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview, uiscrollview

Im trying to create an infinite scroll type thing with Instagram using UITableView and AFNetworking however I get this error when I get to the bottom of the View:

```
CRASH :
 -[__NSCFArray insertObject:atIndex:]: mutating method sent to immutable object
2014-01-05 20:51:41.627 Floadt[1579:70b] STACK TRACE :
 (
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x02b775e4 __exceptionPreprocess + 180
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x027a38b6 objc_exception_throw + 44
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x02b773bb +[NSException raise:format:] + 139
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x02bfe365 -[__NSCFArray insertObject:atIndex:] + 101
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x02b3b2d0 -[NSMutableArray insertObjects:count:atIndex:] + 208
    5   CoreFoundation                      0x02b3af69 -[NSMutableArray insertObjectsFromArray:range:atIndex:] + 425
    6   CoreFoundation                      0x02b3ad15 -[NSMutableArray addObjectsFromArray:] + 661
    7   Floadt                              0x0003f5ec __42-[StreamViewController nextInstagramPage:]_block_invoke + 284
    8   Floadt                              0x0001edfb __64-[AFJSONRequestOperation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:failure:]_block_invoke91 + 43
    9   libdispatch.dylib                   0x035247f8 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 15
    10  libdispatch.dylib                   0x035394b0 _dispatch_client_callout + 14
    11  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0352775e _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 340
    12  CoreFoundation                      0x02bdca5e __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 14
    13  CoreFoundation                      0x02b1d6bb __CFRunLoopRun + 1963
    14  CoreFoundation                      0x02b1cac3 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 467
    15  CoreFoundation                      0x02b1c8db CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
    16  GraphicsServices                    0x0453c9e2 GSEventRunModal + 192
    17  GraphicsServices                    0x0453c809 GSEventRun + 104
    18  UIKit                               0x01936d3b UIApplicationMain + 1225
    19  Floadt                              0x0006646d main + 141
    20  libdyld.dylib                       0x037cb70d start + 1
    21  ???                                 0x00000001 0x0 + 1
)
```

Here is how I am making my code, what confuses me is the fact that all my Arrays are Mutable but it states that the mutating method was sent to an immutable object:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    if (scrollView.contentOffset.y == roundf(scrollView.contentSize.height-scrollView.frame.size.height)) {
        NSDictionary *page = instagramResponse[@"pagination"];
        NSString *nextPage = page[@"next_url"];

        [[InstagramClient sharedClient] getPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",nextPage] parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

            instagramResponse = [responseObject mutableCopy];
            [instagramResponse addEntriesFromDictionary:responseObject];
            [instaPics addObjectsFromArray:responseObject[@"data"]];
            [self.tableView reloadData];

        } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
            NSLog(@"Failure: %@", error);
        }];
    }
}
```

Comment: The stack trace doesn't lie.  Look for the `addObjectsFromArray:` call in the block method inside `[StreamViewController nextInstagramPage:]`.  Once you find the name of the array, look for places it might be set to an immutable object.

Answer (score 1):

before `addEntriesFromDictionary` the copy of Dictionarylike this

```
NSDictionary *copyOfDic = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary: originalDic copyItems: YES];
if (copyOfDic ) {
    [destination addEntriesFromDictionary: copyOfDic ];
    [copyOfDic release];
}
```

or

```
[instaPics addObjectsFromArray:[responseObject[@"data"]mutable copy]];
```

or

Your @property yourarray is either initialized with an NSArray or declared copy.

because both would be lead to this error/exception message since the backing ivar would point to an (immutable) NSArray.

If you have declared your property to be of NSMutableArray type, use strong as the storage modifier instead of copy.

Comment: I tried doing what you stated however I am getting the same error. The NSMutableArray was already strong.

Comment: which line you get exception do you try with NSZombie. let me know

Comment: The error occurs in the line     `[instaPics addObjectsFromArray:responseObject[@"data"]];` I have edited the way I am trying to page within the app

Comment: [instaPics addObjectsFromArray:[responseObject[@"data"]mutable copy]]; did you tried this